# The Dissertation of F. J. van der Linden

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, quadratic-forms

Does anyone have access to the 1984 dissertation of Franciscus Jozef van der Linden under Hendrik Lenstra? It is called *Euclidean Rings with two infinite primes*. The theory is that this has the details on Lenstra's three non-principal norm-Euclidean classes for real quadratic fields. In case it is a matter of copying a few pages, apparently the discussion takes place in Section 5.5; this is according to the 2012 dissertation of Pierre Lezowski:
http://genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/id.php?id=170068  and
http://www.math.u-bordeaux1.fr/~plezowsk/index.php

Note that I have written to both Pierre Lezowski and Hendrik Lenstra, and something may come of that in time. On the other hand, sometimes email gets shunted to spam folders, or people lack adequate time to reply.

http://genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/id.php?id=47922

[image]

See also:

"The Defenestration of Ermintrude Inch"

"The Love Song of J. Alfred Prufrock"

"The Prime of Miss Jean Brodie"

"The Picture of Dorian Gray"

"The Injudicious Prayers of Pombo the Idolater"

"The Coronation of Mr Thomas Shap"

Comment: I found the thesis (a hard copy, no digital version available) in the catalogue of the library of the University of Amsterdam (http://permalink.opc.uva.nl/item/002887553). I won't be in town for the coming week, but if you haven't found another version by then it would be no problem to send you a scan.

Comment: @PhilipvanReeuwijk, thank you. Berkeley does not have it.

Comment: I don't know why, or what it says about me, but I read the second title at the end as "The Love Song of Ben Affleck".

Comment: @AsafKaragila, understandable. Afflemon is unavoidable.

Comment: Is the prime of Miss Jean Brodie congruent to 1 modulo 4?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, yes,  57, same as Grothendieck

Comment: Incidentally, some anonymous user has been suggesting edits that remove your "see also" references.

Comment: @S.Carnahan, I noticed that, and that you rejected the suggestion. Thank you. I'll think about it. I am aware that not everyone shares my sense of humor. At the same time, I prefer to know who it is, if someone wishes to alter my writing. I regard the story/book titles as pretty harmless. Well, off to bed.

Comment: The Guide for the Perplexed: the first story is by Arthur C. Clarke, appearing in Tales from the White Hart; (1957). The last two are by Lord Dunsany, appearing in The Book of Wonder; (1912).

Comment: @PhilipvanReeuwijk, Benjamin found the thesis published in some sort of series, and available online. See his answer, with link. Thanks again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The thesis can be found in full [here](http://oai.cwi.nl/oai/asset/12735/12735A.pdf).

Section 5.5 begins on pdf 84/216 (p. 72).

---

**FYI:** Because the thesis was published through Centrum voor Wiskunde en Informatica, you can simply search for it through their website: https://repository.cwi.nl/

Comment: You're welcome! Hope you find what you seek.

Comment: It's pretty good. It does not give the explicit values desired, but gives methods that should lead to  estimates.